# update multiple records mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How do I update multiple records using MongoDB in NodeJS?

```js
Booking.updateMany(
    { '_id': { '$in': ObjectId(req.params.reservation_ids) } },
    { $set: { "status": "2" }},
    { "multi": true }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany
Like:

```
    await Booking.updateMany({title: "something"}, {"$set":{status: "done"}});
```